# Software simulation from ARM Cortex-M0

Tags: arm, simulator

Is there a software simulator for ARM Cortex-M0 ?

Answer (score 5):

I have a thumb only (not thumb2) instruction set simulator, goto github and search for thumbulator.  Depends on what you are trying to do, could compile for thumb for a while then switch to thumb2 later.

For arm I found a behavioral verilog model out on a university site.

For thumb2 you might check and see if qemu supports it, I know there is support for the stellaris cortex-m3 so that may put you close enough.

Comment: I just learned that the cortex-m0 is thumb only so my thumb simulator may be useful to you after all.  You would have to add your own peripherals.

Comment: As I recall, the CM0 is not thumb-only.  It doesn't cover the breadth of thumb-2 instructions that the CM3 does for example, but there are a few thrown in there (MRS / MSR, NOP, WFI / WFE, etc.).  But the thumb simulator might still be very useful to Rumple.

Comment: from the armv6-m trm it shows only a few, maybe 4 thumb2 instructions are there, also other websites confirming no thumb 2, plus spending an evening trying to figure out why both gcc and llvm's were producing broken thumb2 code for very simple instructions, moves, loads, stores, then read the manual to see it wouldnt work.

Answer (score 2):

There is no FOSS simulator. ARM documentation license prohibit documentation use for making simulator. You have to pay money to ARM to use documentation for simulation purposes and so all ARM simulators for latest architectures are non free.

Comment: there is a work-in-progress port of qemu to additional corext-m devices, currently upstream only has support for m3's https://github.com/sushihangover/qemu

Answer (score 0):

You can download & use the free version of Keil uVision (limited to 32k)

Answer (score 0):

IAR Embedded Workbench (www.iar.se) includes a simulator for Cortex cores. It is free (kickstarter version) up to 32kb of code size.